# There is a way to run an action in klipper showing the terminal?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu

I'm using Kubuntu 21.04 and I had set the following action in klipper

`youtube-dl %s`

It works as expected: if I have the direction of a youtube video in the clipboard it download it, however the action happens silently. I want to know if there is a way to show the terminal when calling this action to see the progress of the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see a terminal showing the action, you will need to launch the command in a virtual console. For the Konsole terminal emulator, following action may work:

```
konsole --noclose -e youtube-dl %s
```

The --noclose option ensures that the window remains open after the `youtube-dl` command has finished. You could leave that option out if you prefer just to see the download starting, and prefer that terminal window to automatically be closed.